# NOT a specific word at ending in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess

I have those strings:

```
"/page/test/myimg.jpg"
"/page/test/"
"/page2/test/"
"/page/test/other"
```

I want true for all strings starting with /page/test except when it ends with `.jpg`.

Then I did: `/^\/page\/test(.*)(?!jpg)$/`.
Well, it's not working. :\

It should return like this:

```
"/page/test/myimg.jpg" // false
"/page/test/" // true
"/page2/test/" // false
"/page/test/other" // true
```

Comment: You can't really do negative look ups like that without doing a bit of trickery. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word where this has been answered thoroughly.

Comment: What language are we talking about here?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative look behind anchored to end:

```
/^\/page\/test(.*)(?<!\.jpg)$/
```

---

For clarity, this regex will match any input that *doesnt end in `.jpg`:

```
^.*(?<!\.jpg)$
```

#### Edit (now must work in JavaScript too)

JavaScript doesn't support look behinds, so this ugly option must be used, which says that at least one of the last 4 characters must be other than `.jpg`:

```
^.*([^.]...|.[^j]..|..[^p].|...[^g])$
```

Comment: Thanks! Just miss the `<` at `?<!`. For complete explanation, what can I use in javascript regex for `?<!`?

Comment: You can use any limited-length expression. If you need `.*`, limit it eg `.{0,99}`

Comment: I am sorry. `?<!` does not exists in javascript regex. Do you know a substitute for it (if it at least exists)? I'm doing this same thing in .htaccess and javascript.

Comment: Then that is a different question - I have updated the question tags and provided an answer.

Comment: No ugly option needed (and lookbehind is not required). See my simple answer.

Answer (score 4):

Easily done with JavaScript:

```js
/^(?!.*\.jpg$)\/page\/test/
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that javascript doesn't support look behinds, but does support look aheads.